# Duplicate session_id PRIMARY KEY for session in F3 (DB session)

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

longtime lurker, first-time poster. Sorry for any trouble!

I'm using FatFreeFramework, which I like a lot (donated some money). I started using DB backed sessions ([\DB\SQL\Session](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/lib/db/sql/session.php)) and they work nicely for the most part. PHP version 7.4.

In my logs i can see repeated 500 errors:

> 500 Internal Server Error:   PDOStatement: Duplicate entry
> 'nd4n440i8usfekd5llskhdv58e' for key 'PRIMARY'
> [app/libs/db/sql/mapper.php:458] DB\SQL->exec()
> [app/libs/db/cursor.php:245] DB\SQL\Mapper->insert()
> [app/libs/db/sql/session.php:97] DB\Cursor->save()

I thought that maybe there's too little entropy, so I added and registered ("create_sid" function returning random bytes.

```
function genSidId(){
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(40));
}
```

I referenced it in `session_set_save_handler` [part of the class](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/lib/db/sql/session.php#L201). `Session_id` got longer, but it didn't solve the duplicate primary key errors.

I could probably rewrite parts of the library to check if `session_id` exists, or maybe use "replace into" (which I've seen referenced in some similar questions) but maybe somebody has a better solution? Or maybe I'm missing some setup in F3?

Errors happen 4-6 times a day, the website gets thousands of visits per day.

Comment: Do you have a master/slave setup for your database?

Comment: And out of curiosity have you used another interface for saving your sessions as a test and see if the problem persists using file, memcached, jig etc based storage?

Comment: It's a shared hosting. There's only one db server.

I've only used DB sessions on the website. Prior to deploy i used file based sessions (default, provided by system), but load was tiny compared to current number of visitors. So i'd say it's inconclusive.

Comment: I'd say give it a shot to swap out the DB sessions for file based sessions. I've looked at the code you did, read up on some PHP Docs, look at the DB\SQL\Session class and nothing immediate stood out to me. It doesn't make sense why it would try to write the same session id twice. If you were on a master/slave setup I might cry slave lag, but since you aren't, it'd be nice to try out a different method to find out one of 2 things: either there's something wrong with the SQL session implementation or there's something going on with you PHP settings causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've fixed errors by rewriting \DB\SQL\Session.

```
class ASession {

    protected $_agent,$_ip;

    function open($path,$name) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    function close() {
        return TRUE;
    }

    function read($id) {
        $var = DB::var("SELECT data from sessions where session_id = ?", $id);
        return $var ?? '';
    }

    function write($id,$data) {
        $exists = DB::var("SELECT session_id FROM sessions WHERE session_id = ?", $id);
        if (!empty($exists)){
            DB::exec("UPDATE sessions SET data = ?, stamp = ?, ip = ?, agent = ? where session_id = ?", [$data, time(), $this->_ip, $this->_agent, $id]);
        }else{
            DB::exec("INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions(session_id, data, stamp, ip, agent) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ? )", [$id, $data, time(),$this->_ip, $this->_agent]);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    function destroy($id) {
        DB::exec("DELETE FROM sessions where session_id = ?", $id);
        return TRUE;
    }

    function cleanup($max) {
        \Log::logToFile('session_cleanup', $max);
        DB::exec("DELETE FROM sessions where stamp < ?", [time() - intval($max)]);
        return TRUE;
    }

    function genSidId(){
        return bin2hex(random_bytes(40));
    }

    function __construct() {
        session_set_save_handler(
            [$this,'open'],
            [$this,'close'],
            [$this,'read'],
            [$this,'write'],
            [$this,'destroy'],
            [$this,'cleanup'],
            [$this, 'genSidId']
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_commit');
        $fw=\Base::instance();
        $headers=$fw->HEADERS;
        $this->_agent=isset($headers['User-Agent'])?$headers['User-Agent']:'';
        if (strlen($this->_agent) > 300) {
            $this->_agent = substr($this->_agent, 0, 300);
        }
        $this->_ip=$fw->IP;
    }
}
```

Just checking if session_id exists in DB wasn't enough: there were less errors, but still a couple. "INSERT IGNORE" fixed the issue.
Haven't had any complains form users so hopefully sessions work. My own tests were positive.

Seems to me that simple, brutal code is often better than using too many abstractions. Still love F3 though! :)